# Why doesn't my code to count how many times a number can be divided by two work?

Tags: python, function, count

So I was trying to make a code to count how many times a number could be divided by two before reaching 1. I would like to be able to input any number I want and then use it in the function, and afterwards, to use the 'count' variable that was yielded outside the function.

```
print('Pick a number.')
number = input()
count = 0
def powerct(n):
    while n >= 2:
        n = n/2
        count = count + 1
powerct(number)
print(count)
```

Comment: you have to `return count` after the while block ... and get the returned number from your function call. This might help you solve your problems: [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Don't use global variables, at least not for something like this. Learn about the `return` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python variables live in "scopes" - they are only visible while in scope, not out of it.

Functions got theire own scope - more about this here: [Short Description of the Scoping Rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules)

Your `count` from above the function definition is not the same as the `count` inside your function. You can remedy this by returning it from the function (or making it `global` - google this method if you like - I would not recommend it).

```
# python 3.6 -you are probably using 2.x if your input() gives you a number

number = int(input('Pick a number.'))  # you need an int here, not a string
count = 0              # this is not the same count as

def powerct(n):
    count = 0          # this one is a different count
    while n >= 2:
        n = n/2        # this is going to be a float in python 3
        count += 1     
    return count

count = powerct(number)
print(count)
```

should solve your problem.

---

Edit:

```
# python 2.7 -realized youre using that by your use of input() giving int not string
number = input("Pick a number.") 
count = 0              # this is not the same count as

def powerct(n):
    count = 0          # this one is a different count
    while n >= 2:
        n = n/2        
        count += 1     
    return count

count = powerct(number)
print count
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing in the count to the function and returning it.

```
print('Pick a number.')
number = input()
count = 0
def powerct(n,count):
    while n >= 2:
        n = n/2
        count = count + 1
    return count
count = powerct(number,count)
print(count)
```

Alternatively, declare count as a global variable in the function, so it can acces it in its local scope:

```
print('Pick a number.')
number = input()
count = 0
def powerct(n):
    global count
    while n >= 2:
        n = n/2
        count = count + 1
powerct(number)
print(count)
```